# Checking if all books from JSON file are present on web page with Nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, nightwatch.js, data-driven-tests

I'm a newbie with Nightwatch.js and JavaScript in general. I am trying to make a test that will check if all books from JSON file are present on corresponding web page. Also, if there is no books in that page, I want to check if text "There are no products in the category" is present.

I've created page with this command in it:

```
var books = require('../data/books.json')
var x = '';
module.exports = {
    elements: {
        productList: {
            selector: '#product-list',
            locateStrategy: 'css selector'
        }
    },

    commands: [{
        checkBooks: function () {
            this.api
                .elements('css selector', this.elements.productList.selector, function (result){
                    for (i in books.biographies) {
                        x = books.biographies[i].title;
                        for (j in books.biographies.title) {
                            x = books.biographies[i].title[j];
                        }
                    }
                    if (result.status > 0) {
                        console.log(j);
                    } else {
                        this.assert.containsText('#product-list', 'There are no products in the category');
                    }
                })
        }
    }]
}
```

but test is always failing, because it expects from the page to be empty.

Here is the example of my JSON data:

```
"biographies":[  
   {  
      "title":"The Story of my Life",
      "author":"Graham Peterson",
      "publisher":"Mirabilis",
      "ISBN":"########",
      "price":"#.##"
   },
   {  
      "title":"Clear Waters Around Me",
      "author":"Penny Wize",
      "publisher":"Mirabilis",
      "ISBN":"#########",
      "price":"##.##"
   }
]
```

I would appreciate any kind of help. 
Thank you.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering of code and lot of research, I've finally found a solution for this.

```
checkBiographies: function() {
        this.api
            .elements('css selector', this.elements.error.selector, function (result) {
                if (result.value.length > 0) {
                    this.assert.cssClassPresent('#product-list > [class=err]', 'err');
                    console.log('No products!')
                } else {
                    var x = '';

                    for (i in books.biographies) {
                        x += books.biographies[i].title;
                        x += "\n";
                    }
                    console.log(x);
                }
            })
    }
```

Basically, previously I was checking double nested array inside JSON file. I've fixed that and just changed places of conditions. Now I'm first checking if error class is present on the page, and then, if it's not present, I'm doing comparison.

Hope this is going to help someone in the future.

Cheers